# Find Substring Within Column - Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

Suppose I have two columns of data. One is a list of names and the other is a list of peoples' names mixed with other stuff.

For instance, one list has "Bob" while the other might have "blank blank Bob blank blank" amongst other cells. Next row would be "Alice" and in the other "Alice blank blank". (assume they aren't sorted in any way"

What would be a formula to check if a cell in the first column is present (a substring) of any cell in the second column?

Comment: Check out the `FIND` and `SEARCH` functions!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use COUNTIF with a wildcard, e.g. if "Bob" is in A1 then you can check whether that exists somewhere in B1:B10 with this formula

`=COUNTIF(B1:B10,"*"&A1&"*")>0`

that formula will return TRUE if A1 exists anywhere in B1:B10 - it's not case-sensitive

Comment: That's how you do that! I had no idea the "*"&A1&"*" existed. Thank you!

Comment: What if I need the data returned from the column B as text?